# How to convert pyinstaller compiled file to python code

Tags: linux, python, python3, disassembly, decompile

I have file as `foo.n‍`.

When I enter this command:

> `file '/home/mrmahdi/Downloads/Telegram Desktop/foo.n‍'`

I got this:

> `/home/mrmahdi/Downloads/Telegram Desktop/foo.n‍: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=28ba79c778f7402713aec6af319ee0fbaf3a8014, stripped`

Comment: You want to decompile executable binary to Python code, right?

Comment: Yeah i want decompile it.